# Can these be support columns with these brackets

Tags: structural

Is there any way these columns with the top and bottom brackets can be supporting columns. If I can't tell by the brackets, I will need to break into their drywall at places to see if it or another beam is supporting.  I want to remove them.[Images[image: ][1]]

[image: Images3]
Image2

[image: Inage4]

[image: Left POst Bottom]
[image: Left Post top]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, those posts are probably supporting the beam (above). You’ll need to determine the load on the beam, size of existing beam, span from post(s) to wall, and location of footings.

The post without the metal base connector may just be decorative...to match the other post. However, either hire an architect or structural engineer OR submit more info regarding beam sizes, spans, footing locations, etc. for additional help.

Comment: Thanks, what is throwing me off is that the metal brace is installed under drywall on the top and on top of the old linoleum floor.

Comment: @KevinS Ahhh...very interesting. That’s true...if the bearing plater is below the gypsum board, then it can’t be a structural connector. However, you’ll need to determine if there’s a bearing plate up above. Also, you’ll want to check if there’s a footing under the post. (Maybe both posts are decorative.)